# How do I use fstream (specifically ofstream) through a functions parameters

Tags: c++

Hi I'm a `c++` beginner and this is one of my assignments and I'm a bit stuck. This isn't my entire code it's just a snippet of what I need help with. What I'm trying to do is have one function dedicated to exporting everything with that function into a `text` file which is called results.txt. So the line "does this work" should show up when I open the file, but when I run the file I get errors like

> "Error C2065: 'out' : undeclared identifier"
>
> "Error C2275: 'std::ofstream' : illegal use of this type as an expression"
>
> "IntelliSense: type name is not allowed"
>
> "IntelliSense: identifier "out" is undefined"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

//prototypes
void output(ofstream& out);

int main()
{
output(ofstream& out);
    ifstream in;
    in.open("inven.txt");
    ofstream out;
    out.open("results.txt");
return 0;
}

void output(ofstream& out)
{
out << "does this work?" << endl;
}
```

Right now it's really late and I'm just blanking out on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The errors start here: `output(ofstream& out);` What do you think this line is supposed to do?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, this is fine:

```
void output(ofstream& out)
{
    out << "does this work?" << endl;
}
```

However, this is not:

```
int main()
{
    output(ofstream& out); // what is out?
    ifstream in;
    in.open("inven.txt");
    ofstream out;
    out.open("results.txt");
return 0;
}
```

This is the first error you get: "Error C2065: 'out' : undeclared identifier", because the compiler doesn't know about out yet.

In the second fragment you want to *call* output with a specific `ostream&`. Instead of calling a function, you're giving a function declaration, which isn't allowed in this context. You have to call it with the given `ostream&`:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open("inven.txt");
    ofstream out;
    out.open("results.txt");
    output(out); // note the missing ostream&
    return 0;
}
```

In this case you *call* `output` with `out` as parameter.

Comment: `void output(ofstream& out)` is legal but I wouldn't describe it as fine. It would be better written as `void output(ostream& out)` so that the function can be used with any type of output stream.

Answer (score 2):

Since you described yourself as a begginer, I'll answer accordingly and hopefully in a educational manner. Here is what is happening: Think of `fstream`, `ofstream` and `ifstream` as smart variable types (even if you know what classes are, think like that for the sake of **logical clarity**). Like any other variable, you have to **declare it** before you use. After it is declared, that variable can **hold a compatible value**. The `fstream` variable types is for **holding files**. All variations of it hold the same thing, just what they do that is different.

You use the variable to **open a file**, **use it** in your program, then **close**.

Hope this helps