# Using fstream Object as a Function Parameter

Tags: c++, function, fstream

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void vowel(fstream a){
    char ch;
    int ctr = 0;
    while(!a.eof()){
        a.get(ch);
        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U'){
            cout << ch;
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of Vowels: " << ctr;
}

main(){
    fstream a;
    a.open("temp.txt", ios::in);
    vowel(a);
return 0;
}
```

In this simple program , I am trying t count the number of caps Vowels in the file temp.txt. However, I am getting the error:

> ios::ios(ios &) is not accessible in function
>   fstream::fstream(fstream&)

Instead opening the file in the function itself does the job.
Why is it so? 
Thanks a lot

NB:

> [How do I use fstream (specifically ofstream) through a functions parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231730/how-do-i-use-fstream-specifically-ofstream-through-a-functions-parameters)

Here it says, that it should work the way I am trying.

Rick

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An `fstream` object is not copyable. Pass by reference instead: `fstream&`:

```
void vowel(fstream& a)
```

Note you can avoid the call to `open()` by providing the same arguments to the constructor:

```
fstream a("temp.txt", ios::in);
```

and don't use `while(!a.eof())`, check the result of read operations immediately. The `eof()` will only be set when an attempt is made to read beyond the last character in the file. This means that `!a.eof()` will be true when the previous call to `get(ch)` read the last character from the file, but subsequent `get(ch)` will fail and set eof but the code won't notice the failure until after it has processed `ch` again even though the read failed.

Example correct structure:

```
while (a.get(ch)) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Avoiding use of open()... I know about it. Thanks. But what's the problem with eof()? And what to use instead?

Comment: Great. That's why I was getting the last output two times when I was trying to read a file that contained classes and display the contents.
I had found a work-around, by checking if (a.eof()) just before output again, other than checking it in the while loop.
Thanks a lot hmjd

Comment: @hmjd I'm bit confused. what is more efficient, passing stream or  string line .

Comment: Thank you very much for this. To other beginners: `fstram&` goes into the definition of the function, not when you call it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the `fstream` by *reference*:

```
void vowel(fstream& a){ .... }
//                ^ here!
```

Answer (score 2):

try this. instead of sending the file count the vowels in line.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int vowels=0;
void vowel(string a){
    char ch;
    int ctr = 0;
int temp=0;
    for(temp=0,temp<a.length();temp++){
        ch=a.at(temp);
        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U'){
            cout << ch;
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    vowels+=ctr;
}

main(){
    fstream a;
    a.open("temp.txt", ios::in);

string temp;
while(getline(a,temp))
{
vowel(temp);
function2(temp);
function3(temp);


... so on for more then one functions.

}        
vowel(a);
    return 0;
    }
```

if you want to pass the file then use the above ans.(pass fstream by reference).

Comment: This will work too. But I was planning to write multiple functions (that count vowels, count the number of words, number of sentences, etc, etc), and did not want to open the file in each function. You solution will, but will cause me to write the while(getline(a, string temp)) loop again and again for each function.
Thanks

Comment: you open the file only once! call other functions from inside the loop.

Comment: But it will get each line, and O/P.
Example:
No. of Vowels: 5 [For l1]
No. of Words: 2 [For l1]
No. of Vowels: 6 [For l2]
No of Words: 3.... _No, mistake. Sorry. It will work too. Thanks_