# nxn array not printing to outfile?

Tags: c++

The `Robot::printHistory()` member function is supposed to write to a file a robot's 32x32 grid history, how many times a robot has touched (x,y). When running the program, it only outputs the `cout<< " " << index << endl;` portion and ignores the outfile entirely.

```
void Robot::printHistory()
{
    //create output file
    fstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Robot.txt",ios_base::app);

    cout << " " << index << endl; //index will increment automatically for each robot; in constr.

    //print 32x32 grid to outfile with grid[ii][jj] values in.
    for(int ii = 0; ii < GRID_SIZE; ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < GRID_SIZE; jj++)
        {
            outfile << grid[ii][jj] << "\t";
        }
        outfile << endl;
    }
    outfile.close();
}
```

The below `RobotSwarm::printHistory()` member function is supposed to create as many 32x32 grids as there are robots. If there are 5 robots, there will be 5 32x32 grids printed out, each independent of each other. Still, the output is only the `cout` portion from above.

```
void RobotSwarm::printHistory()
{
    int count = 0;
    //open file
    fstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Robot.txt");

    //give the header Robot # followed by the 32x32 grid with grid[ii][jj]values
    for (auto &robot : vecRobots)
    {
        outfile << "Robot" << count++ << "\n";
        robot.printHistory();
    }
    outfile.close();
}
```

I can't figure out how the outfile isn't getting written or even showing in the executable. Does anyone have any idea how to be able to see the 32x32 grid without `cout`ing the whole grid, as I want to output to a file? Thanks.

Comment: `outfile.open("Robot.txt",ios_base::app);` -- There is no check if the file is opened successfully.  Second, we have nothing to go on except your faith that the file really doesn't exist.

Comment: Just to confirm, nothing is being written to outfile? Or are you expecting to see the output in the console just like cout?

Comment: What is the type of grid?

Comment: If you want to avoid the numerous opens/closes associated with the below answer, consider having `RobotSwarm::printHistory()` take an `ostream& os` parameter, and pass this same `os` to `Robot::printHistory()`. Then, you move file operations to outside of the various robot classes, and you can choose to output to `cout` instead if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going on here is confusion between the two functions over who is writing to the outfile when (possibly a data race???). This might be undefined behavior, but when  I replicated the problem all the grids were printed first, then all the labels. Fundamentally, it seems the fstream should be closed in one function before calling the next function. Doing that causes the file to be printed to in the desired order:

```
void writedata() {
    const int SIZE = 5;
    std::array<std::array<int, SIZE>, SIZE> grid {0};
    std::fstream fout;
    fout.open("foo.txt", std::ios::app);
    for (auto arr: grid) {
        for (auto num: arr) {
            fout << num << "\t";
        }
        fout << std::endl;
    }  
    fout.close();
}

void writelabel() {
    std::string label = "Grid # ";
    int count = 0;
    std::fstream fout;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        fout.open("foo.txt", std::ios::app);
        fout << label << std::to_string(count) << "\n";
        fout.close();      //close the file before calling the function for the grid                              
        writedata();
    }
}
```

You can also pass the fstream object created in one function to another by reference `fstream&` which I'd guess is much more efficient than all this opening and closing, but that might break the class functionality (creating a dependency, etc.). 
[Using fstream Object as a Function Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503605/using-fstream-object-as-a-function-parameter)

You probably also want some kind of 'file failed to open' error code checking in here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening the output file twice. Pass the output stream to Robot::PrintHistory:

```
Robot::PrintHistory(std::ostream& outfile)
{// etc
}// do not close the file here either.
```

This way only there is only one object interacting with the file.